# Need to update array of data after select statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I have a `SELECT` statement (see below) that gets a few items from the mysql db and displays them.

I need the script to update the selected items as soon as they are selected with the agent variable so when another user runs the same script they only get records that have no agent assigned to them.

So essentially I need to run a update command but only on the records that have been fetched by that select statement.

```
$agent = $_GET['agent'];
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE processed = '0' AND agent IS NULL LIMIT 5");
$array_data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array_data[] = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);
}
echo json_encode($array_data);
```

Comment: Decompose your issue. What you're really talking about is constructing an `UPDATE` query programmatically.

Comment: no the processed field is for use later on in the script, that bit is ok, it needs to select records that have "NULL" as the agent then update the selected records with the agent variable

Comment: Sorry Tomalak, i was not ignoring you its just that SCUBE has provided me with an answer!!! YAY!!! (i really should has worked that out) programmers block, it happens to the best of us im sure! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expand your while with this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $array_data[] = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]);
        mysql_query("UPDATE $tableName SET agent = 'whateverValueYouNeedHere' WHERE primary_key = $row[theNumberOfYourPrimaryKey]");
}
```

In your above select query you have to make sure the primary key is also fetched (maybe its `$row[0]`). Then you can update the record by its primary key.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooo much scube!!! like i mentioned abouve, i really should have worked that out, you know when you get those days where even the simplest function alludes you!! thanks mate :-)